# resume device /dev/sda1 not found

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse

I created a new VirtualBox machine from a vmdk file that is from an existing OpenSuse VM.

It starts to boot and then i get this:
[image]

However, in the original VM i have ONE drive  with two partitions (sda1, sda2) swap and regular drive.

I would have thought that by adding the that one drive these partitions would show up as they did in the original VM and it would boot normally.

[image]

**What's going on?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems you did use a SCSI controller in your original setup. Using an IDE controller will turn your disk-device into **hda** instead.

Comment: yuuuuuuup!!!!!! (+1)

Comment: had the same issue when porting a VMware machine to Virtualbox. This solved the problem.